# Why does -isMemberOfClass: not work here?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];

if ([arr isMemberOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"YEP!!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"NO!!");
}
```

I get always "NO!!" in console. I tried with Array, NSNumber, NSString. All of them don't seem to work. That's strange. As I get it from the docs, this method should return YES if I test agains the class of the object which is subject of the testing. I'm using the Foundation.h, not Core Foundation (if it makes any difference anyways).

Comment: As a general rule -isMemberOfClass: is never the method you want. There's only a few very specialized situations where it's actually useful. Always use -isKindOfClass: instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `isKindOfClass:` or `respondsToSelector:` as `NSArray` and similar are [class clusters](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34) - you actually get subclasses when creating them. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383978/how-useful-is-the-nsobject-ismemberofclass-method/384044#384044) for some interesting bits on this.

Comment: @gf, what is a "class cluster" ?

Comment: See the apple documentation: http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34

Answer (score 3):

When you create an array using `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:]`, the object you get is actually a member of some concrete subclass of NSMutableArray.  NSMutableArray only exists momentarily in the process of creating the concrete instance.

`-isMemberOfClass:` returns true if the receiver's `isa` pointer is equal to the given class.  `-isKindOfClass:` returns true if the receiver is a member of the given class or any of its subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

did you try isKindOfClass instead of isMemberOfClass?