# usage of isMemberOfClass; returning false

Tags: objective-c

In the code below I thought the second condition would be true, but it is turning out as false. Am I missing something? Please help me understand.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([array class]));

if ([array isMemberOfClass:[NSObject class]]) {

    NSLog(@"Member NSObject"); //Didn't print; 
}

if ([array isMemberOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

    NSLog(@"Member NSArray"); //Didn't print; I don't understand why?
}

if ([array isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]]) {

    NSLog(@"Kind of NSObject"); //Printed; Expected
}

if ([array isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

    NSLog(@"Kind of NSArray"); //Printed; Expected
}
```

**Edit**

I created sub class of NSArray as MyArray and tested its instance using isMemberOfClass as below

```
if ([myArray isMemberOfClass:[MyArray class]]) {

    NSLog(@"Member MyArray"); //Printed;
}
```

So, I guess isMemberOfClass not possible on NSArray, probably on some other framework classes as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. Try inspecting the actual class for that object:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([array class]));
```

The output you get is something like:

```
2013-02-15 23:42:31.272 Project[91998:c07] __NSArrayI
```

So the actual class is `__NSArrayI` (a private subclass of `NSArray`), not `NSArray` itself. Typically, `isKindOfClass:` provides more useful results.

Comment: How do i check NSArray for specific not children of NSArray?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to find objects whose class *is not* a descendant of `NSArray`? If so, you'd just use `![object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]`.

Comment: I mean how to test exactly for a specific class, as isKindOfClass will say 'Yes' even if it find it as descendant. I am under impression isMemberOfClass will exactly do that.

Comment: That sounds right: `isMemberOfClass:` tests whether an object is really an instance of a particular class, excluding descendants.

Comment: Am i right to expect that my second condition should be 'true'?

Comment: No. That object is actually an instance of `__NSArrayI` (a subclass of `NSArray`), not `NSArray`.

Answer (score 2):

NSArray is a class cluster. When you create an object of NSArray, internally it creates the object from its cluster. It adds simplicity to avoid creation of different type of objects depending upon the requirements.

For such cases you should use the function `isKindOfClass`. It checks the completer hierarchy to identify the kind of object.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using isKindOfClass. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383978/how-useful-is-the-nsobject-ismemberofclass-method) for the difference.