# Why isMemberOfClass does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am not clear how isMemberOfClass works. Check the example below. 
Why in the example below is lbl.textColor not a member? Please clear this up for me.

```
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
    lbl.text = @"HI";
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];

    if ([lbl.textColor isMemberOfClass:[UIColor class]]) { // Why Not Memeber
        NSLog(@"Member");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Not Member");
    }

    if ([lbl.text isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]]) {// Why Not Memeber
        NSLog(@"Member");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Not Member");
    }
    if ([imgView.image isMemberOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {// Memeber
        NSLog(@"Member");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Not Member");
    }
```

//Output

```
 2014-12-19 20:17:43.383 Demo[13720:70b] Not Member
 2014-12-19 20:17:45.883 Demo[13720:70b] Not Member
 2014-12-19 20:17:52.772 Demo[13720:70b] Member
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383978/how-useful-is-the-nsobject-ismemberofclass-method

Comment: Calling `NSLog(@"lbl.textColor class=%@", NSStringFromClass([lbl.textColor class]));` will be revealing.

Comment: I have edit the question. Can you please clear me

Comment: The edit is not convincing as the log still shows the misspelled "Memeber".

Answer (score 5):

You will find it revealing to log the class of the colour after it's created:

```
lbl.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
NSLog(@"lbl.textColor class=%@", NSStringFromClass([lbl.textColor class]));
```

and you will probably find the actual class is `UIDeviceRGBColor` or `UICachedDeviceGrayColor` or some such and this is because of [class clustering](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html).

Using `isMemberOfClass` only returns `YES` if the object is a member of the class specified and what you probably want is `isKindOfClass` which returns `YES` if the object is a member of the specified class **or subclass**.

**EDIT** Please note that it appears that `UIColor` doesn't use class clusters and the points made in @Popeye's answer are valid.  My general advice would be to never use `isMemberOfClass` on a system class and then you don't ever need to worry about class clusters.

Comment: I would have said how I voted but apparently you can't anymore but it was good from myself because I never even thought of class clusters

Answer (score 2):

The 1st `if statement` will always be `Not Memeber` because you `NSLog(@"Not Memeber");` for both out comes. The 1st one will return `TRUE` because `lbl.textColor` will return an instance of `UIColor` and the way `isMemberOfClass:` works is like `"isMemberOfClass: Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of a given class"`, taken from the [Apple Documentation for `NSObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isMemberOfClass:). Also taken from the Apple Docs which also re-enforce that this line should return `TRUE` is `"Class objects may be compiler-created objects but they still support the concept of membership. Thus, you can use this method to verify that the receiver is a specific Class object."` and here you are checking that the class returned from `textColor` is of a specific class of `UIColor`

```
if ([lbl.textColor isMemberOfClass:[UIColor class]]) { //  Not Memeber
    NSLog(@"Not Memeber"); // This one is actually returned.
}else {
    NSLog(@"Not Memeber");
}
```

The 2nd one will always be `Not Memember` because `lbl.text` returns an `NSString` **NOT** a `UILabel`

```
if ([lbl.text isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {//Not Memeber
    NSLog(@"Memeber");
}else {
    NSLog(@"Not Memeber"); // Correctly being return 
}
```

The 3rd is correctly returning `Memeber` because `imgView.image` returns a `UIImage`.

```
if ([imgView.image isMemberOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {// Memeber
    NSLog(@"Memeber"); // Correctly being returned
}else {
    NSLog(@"Not Memeber");
}
```

Also it's spelt `Member` not `Memeber`.

**EDIT**

I have just done `NSLog(@"lbl.textColor class=%@", NSStringFromClass([lbl.textColor class]));` as per `Droppy` answer suggests to do and I get `lbl.textColor class=UIColor` so this again says that it should return true for that `if statement`

Comment: So you are saying that the first `if` statement will be `YES`?

Comment: Yes because `lbl.textColor` returns `UIColor` class

Comment: Hello All, I have edit the question. can you please check and clear me

Comment: @Popeye Have you tested that?

Comment: @Droppy Yep and I get true returned on that line. I always test before posting. Also checked the Apple Docs and when doing `textColor` on `UILabel` it returns an instance of `UIColor`.

Comment: Yeah I believe your answer is correct, however it conflicts with the OPs claims of having tested it also.  My answer is more "general advice" about using `isKindOfClass` on system classes and then you don't even need to know if class clusters are being used or not (I don't actually know if `UIColor` uses class clusters - and don't care - however it would appear it doesn't based on your edit).  I also agree the downvoter should have the courage to explain his decision.

Comment: @Droppy no that is fine your answer adds a good point that it could be class clusters I never even thought of that when writing my answer. But I would probably use the `isKindOfClass:` also.